# Are "Jack Frost" Brunnera and "Alexander's Great" Brunnera the same cultivar by a different name?

Tags: shade

Of all the online retailers who sell Brunnera that I can find, they only sell either "Jack Frost" Brunnera or "Alexander's Giant" Brunnera. One I contacted claimed they are identical, but no retailers list them as alternate names in the product listing. A few online resources list them as separate cultivars.  http://www.perennials.com/plants/brunnera-macrophylla-alexanders-great.html

I don't want to waste money if they are the same. And I don't want to buy them from someone who thinks they are the same if they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Having done some research, these plants are very similar; one site describes Alexander's Great as 'a quick growing improvement on Jack Frost, making a larger mound because its leaves are larger', though overall size in terms of height and spread of the plant after five years is not noticeably different from Jack Frost.

The RHS has Alexander's Great listed as an accepted name, but as yet has no further details on the plant, which suggests it is a new variety, probably with Jack Frost as one of its parents. In most respects, both varieties look markedly similar, other than the fact that Alexander's Great does look to have somewhat larger leaves; the names are not interchangeable, so they do appear to be different varieties. Probably the clue is in the name 'Great' meaning the leaves are larger.

If you want Alexander's Great, I, too, would not buy from someone who thinks that and Jack Frost are the same variety...

Comment: It is just amazing how ignorant some nurseries can be about the species they sell...